# WPF: Merger Dictionaries source in separate class

Tags: .net, xaml, mergeddictionaries

In my application I am keeping all my strings in separate library. 
Also I would like to include there the Pack URI for my XAML Merged Dictionaries like this:

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="{x:Static commonStrings:ClassName.UriObject}"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

It is working in runtime, but in design time I have an error

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item"

It is pissing me off, because I have got error in XAML and additionally my designer is unavailable - it shows only on the screen the:

> "An exception was thrown."

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?
Thank you for all answers.